# url rewriting using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs

I have following url rewrite rules

```
 var aURLRewrites = [
        {
            from: "^/ps/app/ui/res/(.*)$",
            to: "/bower_components/sapui5/$1"
        }, {
            from: "^/ps/app/ui(?:/|(?:/index.html))?(?:\\?.*|$)",
            to: "/demo/index.html"
        }, {
            from: "^/ps/app/ui/(.*)$",
            to: "/src/$1"
        }, {
            from: "^/ps/specs/unit/(.*)$",
            to: "/specs/unit/$1"
        }, {
            from: "^/ps/specs/integration/(.*)$",
            to: "/specs/integration/$1"
        }, {
            from: "^/ps/demo/(.*)$",
            to: "/demo/$1"
        }
    ];
```

The problem right now is they are static like tehy can be accessible like http://localhost:8000/ps/app/ui... 
But i want all rewrite rules to be accessible using any path followed by /ps/app/ui eg http://localhost:8000/abc/efg/ps/app/ui... should also work. and original url must also work. 
Can some body know how to add regex before /ps/app/ui ?

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your rules with `(?:/\w+)*`:

```
^(?:/\w+)*/ps/app/ui/res/(.*)$
```

Comment: sorry got no success